# How can I add columns of data from one table to another from a lookup ID number in CSV/Excel?

Tags: sql, excel, wordpress, csv

I am trying to recreate an old ASP member directory and put it into a Wordpress plugin (Ultimate Member) and need to change the data structure before importing.

I exported the old data into a CSV/Excel file that has a couple tables(sheets):

1. Member info table containing 4,000 members (each has a Firm ID field (a number i.e. 344); multiple members can belong to a Firm)
2. Firm table with 1,000 firms (first field is Firm ID)

In the old app the Firm ID number in the Member table calls up all of the fields from the Firm table.   I need this to be all in one table to import.  If I did this manually I would have to look at the Firm ID number for all 4,000 members and then paste in that firms fields from the Firm table into the Member table.  Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: from where you exported the data is it from SQL server or what?

Comment: I think it was from a SQL database, the company did the export for me, I am importing to a Wordpress MySQL database using the plugin: "Import Users from CSV with meta"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a column A with all members, a column B with all IDs and you need a column C with the names if the firms.

If your firm list is in the same document in a second sheet (let's say 'Sheet2', you can type in cell C2:

=vlookup(B2;Sheet2!A:B;2;FALSE)

Then just drag the cell down (double click on the bottom right corner)

Comment: In the sheet “Members” Column A has members, Column B has the Firm ID.   In the sheet “Firms” column A has the Firm ID and I want to look up that number ID and then copy columns B,C,D,E over to the Members sheet and create new columns C,D,E and F.  Does that make sense?

Comment: thank you vlookup did the trick, for anyone else there is a nice video tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJ1MO2xx8wQ